# Riemannian metrics on the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

For an application I'm working on, I'm interested in defining a metric on the tangle bundle $TM$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$. Let $g$ be given in local coordinates as $d\sigma^2_M = g_{ij} dx^i dx^j$. I was wondering if there is anything wrong with defining a metric on the tangent bundle as $d\sigma^2_{TM} = g_{ij}dx^idx^j + g_{ij} dv^i dv^j$ where $g_{ij}$ comes directly from $g$ on $M$ itself. I am aware of the definition of the Sasaki metric and that it is a more "natural" metric. For my application, defining $(TM, \tilde{g})$ in this way makes things simple, but I have not seen it anywhere and I am wondering if there is a reason why.

Comment: Are you using a fixed, global coordinate chart? If not, is this metric independent of the choice of coordinates?

Comment: I'm considering a general manifold, so I just assume I have a chart. How would I check in this case?

Comment: By direct computation, essentially. You can set up two overlapping coordinate systems $(x^i,v^i)$, and $(y^\alpha,u^\alpha)$ and compute the pullback of the metric with respect to the transition function between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, your metric is coordinate dependent; different charts will in general produce a different metric on their common domain. It takes a bit of computation to show this.

Let $x^i$ and $\bar{x}^i$ be coordinates for two overlapping charts (with the indexless $x$, $\bar{x}$ denoting the entire tuple) with a transition function $\varphi(\bar{x})=x$, and denote the Jacobian of this function $\Phi^i_j=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \bar{x}^j}$ We can write the metric in these coordinates as $g$ and $\bar{g}$ respectively, related by $\bar{g}=\varphi^* g$, or equivalently $\bar{g}_{ij}=\Phi^k_i\Phi^l_j g_{kl}$.

These coordintes induce coordinates $(x,v)$ and $(\bar{x},\bar{v})$ on $TM$ in the standard way. Above a particular point, we have $\bar{v}^j\bar{\partial}_j=\bar{v}^j\Phi^i_j\partial_j$, and thus $v^i=\Phi^i_j\bar{v}^j$. Using this, we can write out the transition function and all of its derivatives:
$$\begin{align}
x^i&=\varphi^i(\bar{x}) &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
v^i&=\Phi^i_j(\bar{x})\bar{v}^j \\
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar{x}^j}&=\Phi^i_j(\bar{x}) &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial\bar{x}^j}&=\frac{\partial\Phi^i_k}{\partial\bar{x}_j}(\bar{x})v^k \\
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar{v}^j}&=0 &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial\bar{v}^j}&=\Phi^i_j(\bar{x})
\end{align}$$
Now we can actually compare metrics on $TM$ given by your definition. I'll refer to the basis of partial derivatives on $TTM$ as $e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, $f_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial v^i}$ and likewise for $\bar{e}_i$, $\bar{f}_i$. Let $h=g_{ij}dx^idx^j+g_{ij}dv^idv^j$ and $\bar{h}=\bar{g}_{ij}d\bar{x}^id\bar{x}^j+\bar{g}_{ij}d\bar{v}^id\bar{v}^j$. If this definition is independent of coordinates, we must have $\psi^*h=\bar{h}$, where $\psi(\bar{x},\bar{v})=x,v$ is the transition function. We run into a problem on the $dx^idx^j$ components, though:
$$
(\psi^*h)_{ij}=(\psi^*h)(\bar{e}_i,\bar{e}_j)=h(\psi_*\bar{e}_i,\psi_*\bar{e}_j)
$$
$$
=h\left(\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial\bar{x}^i}e_k+\frac{\partial v^k}{\partial\bar{x}^i}f_k,\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial\bar{x}^j}e_l+\frac{\partial v^l}{\partial\bar{x}^j}f_l\right)=\Phi^k_i\Phi^l_jg_{kl}+\frac{\partial\Phi^k_m}{\partial\bar{x}^i}\frac{\partial\Phi^l_n}{\partial\bar{x}^j}v^m v^ng_{kl}
$$
We see we get an extra term related to the derivatives of the Jacobian. Conceptually, both this construction and the Sasaki metric use the fact that $T_vTM$ splits into vertical (tangent to fibers) and horizontal (transverse to fibers) subspaces. The vertical subspace inherits the metric from $TM$ in a straightforward way, but in the absence of the metric there isn't a canonical choice of horizontal subspace. Your construction uses the constant sections $(x,0)$ to choose a horizontal subspace, but this choice is coordinate dependent; the extra term in $\psi^*h$ is related to the degree to which the two coordinate systems do not agree on what a "constant" section is. The Sasaki metric  gets around this by making an intrinsic choice of horizontal subspace using the LC connection.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response. Intuitively, can you explain why there is a problem with the $dx$ component? I was more worried about $dv$. I am thinking about a component in $TTM$ as follows. Let $\gamma(t) = (p(t), v(t))$ be a curve in $TM$. Then $v(t) \in T_pM$, but it is not required that $v(t) = p'(t)$. A tangent vector to this curve is a pair $(v^h(t), v^v(t))$ where $v^h(t) = p'(t)$ (i.e., the velocity to the curve $p(t)$) and $v^v(t) = v'(t)$ (i.e., the acceleration to $v(t)$). I would have thought then that it would be fine to use $g$ on $v^h$ like for $TM$, but $v^v$ may be trickier.

Comment: If by "acceleration" you mean the covariant  derivative $\nabla_{p'}v$, then what you are describing is exactly the Sasaki metric. Note that you can't differentiate vector fields along curves in an intrinsic way without using the connection, and that without that there isn't a canonical way to split $v$ into components. The vertical component is accomplised by the vertical lift, i.e. the canonical isomorphism $T_vT_pM\cong T_pM$. The horizontal subspace requires choosing a preimage of $d_v\pi$, which cannot be done canonically.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just to follow up on this, if the manifold does admit a single global chart - say we are considering $R^p$ and hence $TM \simeq R^{2p}$, then this construction is valid because we do not have to worry about agreement between overlapping charts?

Comment: Provided you specify that global chart as an extra piece of data, that construction would be fine fine. A manifold that admits one global chart admits many others, and some will induce different metrics. This amounts to choosing a flat connection unrelated to the metric and using that connection in place of the LC connection to define the splitting of TTM.